# What is the furthest from Earth that a military spacecraft is thought to have been intentionally deployed or moved to?

Tags: orbit, record, military, space-surveillance

Space.com's [Space Force plans to send a patrol probe out past the moon](https://www.space.com/us-space-force-military-afrl-chps-moon-satellite) includes a quote from the new AFResearchLab video [Cislunar Highway Patrol System (CHPS)](https://youtu.be/yOnPBE1rZNY).

> "Until now, the United States space mission extended 22,000 miles [35,400 kilometers] above Earth," the video states, **referring to the altitude at which geostationary satellites fly.** "That was then; this is now."
>
> "The Air Force Research Laboratory is extending that range by 10 times and the operations area of the United States by 1,000 times, taking our reach to the far side of the moon into cislunar space, far beyond the crowd," the video's narrator continued.

**Question:** Is GEO or just slightly above it the furthest from Earth that any military spacecraft is thought to have been intentionally deployed or moved to or through? If not, *what is* the furthest from Earth to which this has been done?

Further reading:

- [A Primer on Cislunar Space](https://www.afrl.af.mil/Portals/90/Documents/RV/A%20Primer%20on%20Cislunar%20Space_Dist%20A_PA2021-1271.pdf) M. J. Holzinger, C. C. Chow, P. Garretson, Approved for public release: distribution unlimited. AFRL 2021-1271

---

[image: screenshot from the new AFResearchLab video "Cislunar Highway Patrol System (CHPS)" https://youtu.be/yOnPBE1rZNY]

Comment: I hope it's better than the [television series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHiPs).

Comment: PR-puffery tag again.

Comment: @OrganicMarble *relevance?* This is a question about a greatest distance; the reference is included as prior research only. You're just being grumbly; these serial "puffery" comments are irrelevant, distracting, unhelpful and un-actionable, therefore not appropriate. If you have something relevant, helpful and actionable, please expand on that.

Comment: Another in your long (and interesting) series of questions based on something dumb in a PR release. I understand it can be hard to keep up the question pace sometimes.

Comment: @OrganicMarble This question is not *based on* the statement. Once again this is a question about a greatest distance; the reference is included as prior research only, the statement by the  Air Force Research Laboratory is not a premise or the basis of the question, it's the question's *stimulus*. I don't think a "Is it really 10X?" question is as interesting because a single datapoint can answer it. Asked this way ("What is the furthest?") allows for multiple answer and a lot more information to be presented here. I really think the question is fine as-is.

Comment: @OrganicMarble If there are actionable recommendations for improving it I'm all ears. But these ambiguous "puffery" comments seem more gratuitous than helpful or actionable.

Comment: @OrganicMarble The PR-puffery has made me avoid answering many of this user's questions.

Comment: @DavidHammen Define "many". and while you're at it  *name just three* for example. Most of your claims about me have been without merit, I suspect this one is the same, but if you can support it I'll take a look.

Comment: @DavidHammen claim 1) I don't like to vote to close: I have voted to close 761 times here and, 476 times in Astronomy SE. 2) my questions are *based on images*: They're not. They do include them but I try very hard to also explain what's in the image whenever it is a part of the question.  3) "[you're just posting this question to get rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345482/303080)" I'd cap my rep if I could but I can't. I've spent 56,000 reputation in 465 bounties here in Space and  19,950 in reputation on 176 bounties in Astronomy. I suspect your current claim is also unsupportable.

Comment: @uhoh There are no votes to close on this question. It's the superfluous and parenthetical "(they're bringing back CHiPS!)" in the title that's PR puffery, the excessive reliance on superfluous imagery (also PR puffery), along with the fact that you ask multiple questions per day, many of them on trivia. This is not your site alone. There are many experts here who avoid answering your questions.

Comment: @DavidHammen can you rank these problems in order of grievousness? a) "superfluous and parenthetical" phrases in titles, b) *reliance* on images (not just inclusion), c) multiple questions per day, d) questions that "many experts here... avoid answering" and while you are at it support claims b and d with three examples each? I don't yet believe those and feel they are additional unsupportable claims. For a moment imagine someone said "DH that calculation you did is completely wrong!" and walked away without telling you which one. You would want that *supported* with a specific example.

Comment: @DavidHammen [What exactly is "PR puffery"? Where exactly is the harm, and how to distinguish between that and prior research or just plain catchy title-izing?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2926/12102)

Comment: A CHiPS *music* link?  Wow, someone's excited.

Comment: **note:** I'll leave the post unedited *for now* so that people can see it *as is* while discussing it in the meta question linked above.

Comment: I edited the question because there was some garbage text on the end of it. There's no reason to leave garbage lying around for discussion.

Answer (score 17):

There are other satellites that were launched that went beyond GEO:

[SOLRAD 11A and SOLRAD 11B](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nmc/spacecraft/display.action?id=1976-023C) by the US Naval Research Laboratory:

> SOLRAD 11A was one of a pair of identical satellites that were placed
> in a circular equatorial orbit of 20 earth radii.
>
> Funding Agency : Department of Defense-Department of the Navy (United States)

Also [Clementine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clementine_(spacecraft)) was built and operated by the Naval Research Laboratory:

> Clementine (officially called the Deep Space Program Science
> Experiment (DSPSE)) was a joint space project between the Ballistic
> Missile Defense Organization (previously the Strategic Defense
> Initiative Organization) and NASA, launched on January 25, 1994. Its
> objective was to test sensors and spacecraft components in long-term
> exposure to space and to make scientific observations of both the Moon
> and the near-Earth asteroid 1620 Geographos.

Comment: I think you accidentally a link for Clementine there, so I edited one in for you. For those who don't naturally think in Earth-radii, like me, 20 of them is ~127562.0 km, comfortably further out than Vela.

Comment: Is a solar research satellite a military spacecraft if it is launched by the US Naval Research Laboratory instead of the NASA?

Answer (score 14):

It is fairly trivial to disprove the "not above GEO" line, at least... [Vela 1A](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nmc/spacecraft/display.action?id=1963-039A) was operated by the [USAF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vela_1A) and has a circular orbit in HEO at ~100000km perigee, for example. Things in [Molniya orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molniya_orbit) (such as [Kosmos 2105](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosmos_2105) might reasonably have an apogee above GEO too, though not as far out as Vela and I'm not sure if the US military operated things in those sorts of orbit.

I haven't found any mention of any other military satellites further out that that. As far as I can tell, most modern military programs operate larger numbers of satellites in lower orbits (like the DSP and SBIRS programs that are the modern counterparts of Vela). There are some papers talking about the potential usefulness of military communications satellites in Lagrange points, but I don't see any obvious evidence that anyone has bothered doing that so far.

Comment: Nice answer, was coming here to mention Vela.

Comment: I suspect you meant apogee rather than perigee with regard to Molniya orbits. Their perigees can be rather low. Satellites in Tundra orbits also go higher than GEO altitude.

Comment: @DavidHammen oops, you are quite right. Fixed.